# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ApiResponse>'

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular project, I have a function defined in my service that is supposed to call my API.

This function looks like this:

```
apiCall(type: string, path: string, params: string[], data: any, headers?: HttpHeaders) {
let result = new Observable();
result = this.http.get(API_URL + '/' + path, {headers});

return result.pipe(
      tap(
        (response: ApiResponse) => {
          // console.log(response);
          return {...response};
        }),
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
}
```

However, on this last line of code I get the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<ApiResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, ApiResponse>'.   Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.     Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ApiResponse>'.       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ApiResponse'.
```

I tried to search for this error, but I haven't find a solution anywhere.

The weird thing is that this same code was working in other projects so I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 5):

By doing this:

```
let result = new Observable();
result = this.http.get(API_URL + '/' + path, {headers});
```

You are assigning a new `Observable` and then replacing it with another `Observable` from the Angular framework. Besides the fact that it's useless, TypeScript infers the type of `result` from its first assignment: `Observable<unknown>`.

So just write this instead:

```
const result = this.http.get<ApiResponse>(API_URL + '/' + path, { headers });
```